# Multiple Converter based on same property updating undelrying value

Tags: c#, wpf, converters

In the code below I'm trying to display "RateValue" as both a decimal and a percentage using a converter.

The below GridColumn code is within a ComboBoxEdit popout template.

What I'm seeing is that when all GridColumns are added the underlying "RateValue" ends up being the same in both cases. However when I only have one or the other they are showing the right values.

So having both appears to be changing the underlying source value.

Am I missing something obvious here?

Thanks

```
<dxg:GridColumn MinWidth="80" Header="Rate (%)">
    <dxg:GridColumn.Binding>
        <Binding Path="RateValue" Converter="{StaticResource DecimalToFourDecimalPlacesPercentageConverter}" Mode="OneWay" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"/>
    </dxg:GridColumn.Binding>
</dxg:GridColumn>

<dxg:GridColumn Header="Rate (Decimal)">
    <dxg:GridColumn.Binding>
        <Binding Path="RateValue" Converter="{StaticResource DecimalToFourDecimalPlacesConverter}" Mode="OneWay" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"/>
    </dxg:GridColumn.Binding>
</dxg:GridColumn>

<converters1:NumericToStringConverter x:Key="DecimalToFourDecimalPlacesPercentageConverter" Format="0:N4" Multiplier="100"/>
<converters1:NumericToStringConverter x:Key="DecimalToFourDecimalPlacesConverter" Format="0:N4" Multiplier="1"/>

public class NumericToStringConverter : IValueConverter
{
    private static readonly ILog Logger = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(NumericToStringConverter));
    public string Format { get; set; }
    public int Multiplier { get; set; }

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (!(value is decimal)) return Binding.DoNothing;
        try
        {
            var v = (decimal?) value;
            return string.Format("{" + Format + "}", Multiplier*v);
        }
        catch (FormatException ex)
        {
            Logger.Error(string.Format("Failed to format '{0}'", value), ex);
        }
        return Binding.DoNothing;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: As a note, setting `UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"` on a OneWay Binding is pointless. UpdateSourceTrigger only affects TwoWay or OneWayToSource Bindings.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. I was just adding changes to see if they would have any impact. But like you say a one time binding doesn't care if the source updates. Thanks

Comment: "*a one time binding doesn't care if the source updates*" - that was not was I was saying. UpdateSourceTrigger controls what happens when the *target* property changes, or more precisely how and when exactly the source property is updated as a result of a change of the target property. This is only relevant for Bindings that do update their source property at all, i.e. TwoWay and OneWayToSource. All other Bindings, e.g. the ordinary *OneWay*, don't do that.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with DevExpress's WPF control, but assume they work like official one, there's no need for converter, `StringFormat` should be enough.

```
<dxg:GridColumn MinWidth="80" Header="Rate (%)">
    <dxg:GridColumn.Binding>
        <Binding Path="RateValue" StringFormat="P4"/>
    </dxg:GridColumn.Binding>
</dxg:GridColumn>

<dxg:GridColumn Header="Rate (Decimal)">
    <dxg:GridColumn.Binding>
        <Binding Path="RateValue" StringFormat="N4"/>
    </dxg:GridColumn.Binding>
</dxg:GridColumn>
```

If that doesn't work, change your converter to

```
public class NumericToStringConverter : IValueConverter
{
    private static readonly ILog Logger = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(NumericToStringConverter));

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        try
        {
            return string.Format(parameter.ToString(), value);
        }
        catch (FormatException ex)
        {
            Logger.Error($"Failed to format {value}", ex);
        }

        return Binding.DoNothing;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

then change other parts to

```
<dxg:GridColumn MinWidth="80" Header="Rate (%)">
    <dxg:GridColumn.Binding>
        <Binding Path="RateValue" Converter="{StaticResource MyDecimalToStringConverter}"
            ConverterParameter="P4"/>
    </dxg:GridColumn.Binding>
</dxg:GridColumn>

<dxg:GridColumn Header="Rate (Decimal)">
    <dxg:GridColumn.Binding>
        <Binding Path="RateValue" Converter="{StaticResource MyDecimalToStringConverter}"
            ConverterParameter="N4"/>
    </dxg:GridColumn.Binding>
</dxg:GridColumn>

<converters1:NumericToStringConverter x:Key="MyDecimalToStringConverter"/>
```

Comment: Thanks - the first option didn't work but modifying the Converter is a cleaner solution that what I had. For some reason even with the first option the underlying value shows the same % formatting.

Comment: I've upvoted your answer, but still the root cause of both columns showing the same value remains.

Comment: @CiaranMartin Sorry, I can't do any test since I don't have DevExpress toolkit. But still happy to help.

Comment: No problem Alex. Thanks for your help so far.